# Change $_GET string on a form with multiple select

Tags: php, forms, select, get

I have a form with a couple of multiple selects and the url I get when submitting the form is something like this:

tld.com/?var1=opt1$var1=opt2&var1=opt3&var2=opt1&var2=opt2

The url I woul like to obtain is:

tld.com/?var1=opt+opt2+opt3&var2=opt1+opt2

I do not want to use the $_POST method with the options stored in an array because I want the url to be unique for any custom search.

The form looks something like this:

```
<form action="" method="get"> 
    <select name="var1" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="var1">one</option>
        <option value="var2">two</option>
        <option value="var3">three</option>
        <option value="var4">four</option>
        <option value="var5">five</option>
    </select>
    <select name="var2" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="var1">one</option>
        <option value="var2">two</option>
        <option value="var3">three</option>
        <option value="var4">four</option>
        <option value="var5">five</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why foo=1+2+3 instead of the *standard* foo=1&foo=2&foo=3?

Comment: I don't have access to the script that handles the url variables ... I only have acces to the form that has to generate the url. And the structure needs to be ?foo=1+2+3 for multiple values

Comment: @Quentin since this is tagged PHP, the syntax is `foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3` you can optionally supply keys: `foo[bar]=1&foo[baz]=2`. PHP transparently translates that into an array structure. The input fields would look like this: `<input name="foo[]" value="1">`.

Comment: I *seriously* recommend getting access to that script or telling someone who does have access to it to fix it. Parsing standard form data structures is going to be easier and more robust then trying to make forms send data in non-standard ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build 2 arrays on client side and post it through the form, but on server side You will get 2 arrays and make pairs from them anyway. Do You **really** need it?

It'll be something like

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
var myKeys = new Array();
var myValues = new Array();
$("#myForm input").each(function(n,element){
    myKeys[] = $(element).attr("name");
    myValues[] = $(element).val();
});
$("#hiddenInput").attr("name", myKeys.join('+'));
$("#hiddenInput").attr("value", myValues.join('+'));
return true;
});
```

You will get URL `?name1+name2+name3=value1+value2+value3`

**UPD:** just use `[]` in name attribute:

```
<input name="var1[]" value="param1">
<input name="var1[]" value="param2">
```

You'll get `/?var1=param1+param2`

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough or maybe the values of the variables threw you off. I need the returned url to join the values of one variable together. So if under one select I have values one and two selected the url is now ?foo=one&foo=two I need it to be ?foo=one+two

Comment: So only the values of the variables have to be joined together, the names need to stay separate